Isekai murim manwha where the mc is transported to the world of murim as a blind guy
A long time ago I read a manwha where the mc was a guy who got transported to the world of murim as a blind guy. I don't remember anything else other than when he first encounters people: A group of martial artists went to a mountain to hunt down a demonic tiger beast to become famous, but came across the abandoned house the MC had been "spawned" in. They all introduce themselves and a while later, the tiger finds the place and is about to kill the martial artists, but the MC convinced the tiger to wait a few years, as to give the martial artists a chance to become good people. The tiger believed that the MC must have been a wise sage so he listened to him and became his "disciple". I don't remember what happens directly after that, but I would like to know the name of the manwha, if anyone knows it.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you recall where?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

It sounds like ChronoGo (난가기연, 烂柯棋缘). It is a webcomic based on the chinese fantasy novel or XianXie novel.
The MC goes camping with his friends and finds a game of Go. After placing a single stone on the board, he returns to the campsite, but realizes that he timeslipped 15 days ahead and was reported missing. The MC dies on a hospital bed at the age of 24.
Then the story follows your description.


Wilted leaves beside the board, empty seats between the towering trees, a passerby who chose to put down a stone in the middle of the board, unbeknownst to him eons have passed… Waking up from his slumber, Ji Yuan found himself as a half-blind beggar. Armed with only a sword and his wits, he will venture forth into this danger-filled world.

